# How can i create a model with date index?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, api

I want to access an API with Angular. It gives me an array with a date as an index.

I already tried to create a model, but unfortunately, it doesn't work.
How do I have to change it?

The API answer looks like this

```js
{
    "Information": {
        "Created": "2019-04-25",
        "Version": "1.2"
    },
    "Files": {
        "2019-04-26": {
           'name': 'file1',
           'size': 5,
        },
        "2019-04-25": {
            'name': 'file2',
            'size': 3,
        },
    ...
        }
    }
```

My model looks like this

```
export class Model {
  'Information': {
    'Created': String,
    'Version': String,
  };
  Files: [

    {
     'Date': String,
     'name': String,
     'size': number,
    }
    ];

}
```

Comment: Please post valid json to get quick answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you want here is an [index signature](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/index-signatures.html), which looks like this.

```
export class Model {
  'Information': {
    'Created': string,
    'Version': string,
  },
  'Files': { 
    [date:string]: {
     'name': string,
     'size': number,
    }
  }
}
```

it's stating that class Model has a property Files which is an object with string keys and values that have a string property name, and a number property size.  This doesn't constrain that the keys have to match a certain date pattern, and I don't think there is a way to do that as far as I know.

You can alternatively write a function that maps this response object into an object with a Files array where each object in the array contains the date. That mapping function is a different question but the model would look like this:

```
export class Model {
  'Information': {
    'Created': string,
    'Version': string,
  },
  'Files': { 
    'date': string, // could also type this as Date if you do the conversions
    'name': string,
    'size': number,
  }[]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I don't succeed in writing a function for it. Can you help me?

Comment: Writing a mapping function is a different question, the question here is how to write the type declaration for the object in your question, which I’ve answered. If you’d like to do something else then accept this answer and ask another question with your attempted map function